# Set button background

Tags: c#, wpf

I made and circle as my button. But how I can change the image via code

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource myStyle}" Name="Prj_Button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Height="180" Click="Prj_Button_Click">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse>
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Presentation Interface;component/Images/pic1.png"/>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in code then you need to find `ImageBrush` via `Button.Template` and to do that first you'll need to give `ImageBrush` some name

```
<ImageBrush x:Name="imgBackground" ... />
```

and then in code you can use `FindName`

```
var ib = Prj_Button.Template.FindName("imgBackground", Prj_Button) as ImageBrush;
ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(...);
```

but **`Button` must be already loaded at this point** so you can do it for example in `Window.Loaded` event or somewhere later. It won't work if you do it in `Window` constructor for example

**EDIT**

However I would suggest to use `TemplateBinding` and bind `Ellipse.Fill` with `Button.Background`

```
<Button Name="Prj_Button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Height="180">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

and then you can do in code

```
Prj_Button.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(...));
```